# How to make a repeating pattern in MS Excel with running alphabet letters and numbers

Tags: excel

I've been trying to search the web for an answer with no avail so I decided to ask this here. I have a matrix in MS Excel and I would like to find a repeating pattern on the last row of the matrix such that both the column letter and the row number are running in the pattern.

I tried creating this pattern in the usual way by making few examples in the excel and then dragging the +-sign over the cells. However, only the alphabetical letter runs in the pattern but the numbers do not.

I have below a minimal working example. I have a 4 x 4 matrix and I would like the last row to contain all the diagonal elements of the matrix, that is the numbers 1, 6, 11 and 16. But when I try to repeat the pattern after manually plugging into the first three cells of the blue row as:

```
=A1, =C2, =B3
```

Then when I try to use the +-sign and repeat the pattern only the letter is incremented and I get the value in cell D1 instead. How to create a pattern which reads the diagonal elements of the matrix? Thank you!

[image]

**UPDATE:** Thank you everyone for your help. One addition to previous, many of the given formulas (for example the INDEX-approach) seem to work when my matrix is in the top-left corner of the Excel-file. I noticed that if I add rows or columns to the excel (above and on the left side of the matrix) the formula produces different values, why is this?

Here you see the INDEX-approach prior to adding any columns to excel:

[image]

And here you see the same matrix and formulas after adding one column on the left side of the matrix:

[image]

Comment: Use `COLUMN(A1)` instead of `COLUMN()` to account for any offset.

Comment: Thank you! that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=INDEX($A$1:$D$4,COLUMN(A1),COLUMN(A1))`

Broken down:
`column()` indicates the current column, e.g. in column A it's 1, for B it's 2 etc

`INDEX` looks up the indicated row/column combination in the array

edit1: replaced `indirect` with `index`
edit2: changed column() to column(A1) as suggested by @JvdV

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried the INDEX and it worked, but what if I want to change the position of the matrix in the excel? For example, I added one extra column into the left side of the matrix and the formula produces different numbers, even though the array parameter to INDEX was updated accordingly, why is this?

Comment: P.S. please see my updated post.

Comment: The INDEX-function turned out to be my solution. By replacing the COLUMN() with COLUMN(A1) (as suggested by @JvdV) it did not matter what was the position of the matrix in the Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OFFSET` function, to target a specific row/column using a base cell reference and an offset by a number of rows and columns. In your example here, in `B5` you want to offset by 1 row and 1 column from `A1` and so on...

So you could use the following formula in cell `A5` and then copy across the row:
`=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-1,COLUMN()-1)`

*Edited*: since I realised from @CIAndrews solution that `A5:=COLUMN(A5)` gives the same value as `A5:=COLUMN()`, and the latter is neater.

Comment: OFFSET is volatile and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @BigBen only if recalculation is needed, which isn't the case here. The advantage of OFFSET is that you only need to pass the initial cell `$A$1`, and not the entire range `$A$1:$D$4` (in this case). Depends on the situation, which is preferred

Comment: `INDEX` is  *much* better here. [Offset should be avoided](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-offset-function#:~:text=OFFSET%20is%20a%20%22volatile%20function,the%20edge%20of%20the%20worksheet.)

Answer (score 1):

I created the yellow line with just 1 to 4 incremented.

Then in the blue cells, I have the formula as seen on screen :

[image: My Example]

As the point is just to get RiCi incremented from 1 to n, the formula in the blue cells becomes:

```
=INDIRECT("R"&A5&"C"&A5; FALSE)
```

That you can also drag on the left for autocompletion.

Comment: INDIRECT is volatile and should be avoided whenever possible. Use INDEX instead.